# When I try to execute this code using ./secondo I am getting this error

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

[!I had written this simple program on a different Ubuntu PC using Gedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ZrG.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ZrG.png)

Comment: `chmod +x secondo`

Comment: Don't add a link to the problem. Simply write the error message in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have execute permissions for your executable.

Use

```
chmod +x ./secondo
```

first to correct this.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443789/what-does-chmod-x-filename-and-how-do-i-use-it) question gives more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Try With Sudo Command

```
sudo ./secondo
```